# Getting time from timestamp in hive

Tags: hive, timestamp

I want the time portion from a timestamp column.
E.g. if load_ts= 2016-01-04 11:34:35, then I want only 11:34:35. I have tried using `select concat(hour(load_ts),':',minute(load_ts),':',second(load_ts)) as note_time from rushisourcepart;` but it is not giving correct output.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "correct output"?

Comment: for example if load_ts= 2016-01-04 18:34:56, it gives output as 18:18:18 which is not same as 18:34:56.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr(load_ts, 12)`

```
hive> select substr('2016-01-04 11:34:35', 12);
OK
11:34:35
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But I didn't get it. Why aren't we getting error in this string function substr()? We got error when we tried using concat().

Comment: if this answer works and yours didn't, it looks like the column is actually defined as `string` and not timestamp. Hard to tell without the table definition or the error, which you should have posted for people to be of better help.